# Using c dynamic link library in javascript program

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, dll

I want to use c dll in my javascript code.

Is that possible to do that using **node** ?

Thanks!

Seems to be possible using node.js Addon. Following link can be a starting point:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean `node.js` and the answer is yes. Look up building native modules for `node.js`.

Comment: Seems to be possible using Addons in Node.js http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html